# Which type of Client/Server architecture will be used?

Tags: android, architecture, client-server

I want to develop an Android application based on location based social network like (Google latitude) so which type of client/server will be used for my application. What type of client/server architecture will be used? Is there any helpful website, video, book about client/server architecture related to my application? (I am new in Android development.)

Answer (score 7):

What framework would you like to use on server? What computer languages are you proficient in? Do you want to run this on your own servers or in the cloud?

A generic answer is:

1. Create a [RESTful service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) on server. REST is pretty common and is supported under all modern languages-frameworks. As data format use JSON as it is easier and faster to decode then XML and also maps more nicely to objects. If you use Java/servlets on server you might want to take a look at [Resteasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html).
2. On Android use [HTTPClient](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/) to communicate with your REST server. Use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to produce/consume JSON and map it to your objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use CRest and ignore all these red-eye nerds who say that you should reinvent your own bicycle by using HTTPClient and GSON/org.json. It's not worth it. You need a client-server communication channel, right? Just take it.